# Поиск совпадений в БД

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня в БД есть такая запись
в колонке `name` запись `["Олена","Olena"]` . Обычно вывод записей происходит так

```
select * from profiles where name = "Олена"
```

Как можно вывести все записи где есть совпадения.
Т.е. если ищем по `Olena` или `Олена` что бы нашло необходимую строку?

Comment: `where name = "Олена" or name = "Olena"`?

Comment: *У меня в БД есть такая запись в колонке `name` запись `["Олена","Olena"]`.* Там что, реально JSON-массив в поле? Покажите CREATE TABLE таблицы.

Comment: Если там действительно json, то используйте [Functions That Search JSON Values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html)

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from profiles
where name like '%Олена%'
or name like '%Olena%';
```

Comment: `name = 'Кусок полена'`

Comment: тогда с кавычками